# Updating a User's skills using ManyToManyField in django

Tags: python, django

I've been stuck on this for a few days (new to django) and can't figure out how to update skills for a specific user model using a ManyToManyField, while simultaneously updating a skill model containing a list of skills. Currently when I enter a value in my SkillForm, it updates the skill model properly and creates a dropdown list of skills for a given CustomUser in the admin. However, I can't figure out how to assign a SPECIFIC skill to a particular user. Any help is appreciated.

models.py:

```
class Skill(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length =50, null=True, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name  


class CustomUserManager(UserManager):
    pass

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    objects = CustomUserManager()
    skills = models.ManyToManyField(Skill, null=True, blank=True)
    position = models.CharField(max_length =50, null=True, default='')
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, default='')
```

admin.py:

```
class SkillsInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = CustomUser.skills.through

class SkillAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [SkillsInline ,]

UserAdmin.fieldsets += ('Custom fields set', {'fields': ('position', 'bio',   )}),

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    model = CustomUser
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    form = EditProfile
    inlines = [SkillsInline ,]

admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)
```

forms.py:

```
class SkillForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Skill
        fields =('name' ,)

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        name = cleaned_data.get('name')
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "how to assign a SPECIFIC skill to a particular user". You go to the admin page for the user and select the skill from the inline form, surely? Where exactly are you having trouble?

Comment: That method works, however, I want the user to be able to enter their own skill or list of skills in a form, and then have that entry update 1) their user skills field and 2) the skill model which contains all possible skills in the database. I've tried several form variations with no luck

Answer (score -1):

I see somes problem here :

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    objects = CustomUserManager()
    skills = models.ManyToManyField(Skill, null=True, blank=True)
    position = models.CharField(max_length =50, null=True, default='')
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, default='')
```

When you define an AbstractUser` class, it's mean for Django Authentification purpose, [see the doc here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project), dont do that because it's better to have an unique entry (each user have an unique entry, so you can login each one).

In your system you dont have unique `CustomUser`, here is a solution IMO:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email'), unique=True)

class UserAction(models.Model):
    objects = CustomUserManager()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name="User")
    skills = models.ManyToManyField(Skill, null=True, blank=True)
    position = models.CharField(max_length =50, null=True, default='')
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, default='')

class Skill(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length =50, null=True, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

You now have an unique `User`, a list of `UserAction` that have a related `Skill`

```
user = User.objects.create(email='my@email.com')
skill = Skill.objects.create(name="shadow step")
user_action = UserAction.objects.create(user=user, skill=skill, position='HERE', bio='10')
```

Is that what you needed ?

Comment: Thanks I will try this. However, I was following the steps on this blog: https://wsvincent.com/django-allauth-tutorial-custom-user-model/ which suggests using a CustomUser model. I believe the problem is: when a skill is entered in a form, I need it to update the User skills or vice versa but can't achieve this with my current set-up.

Comment: I should also mention that all of my other fields update appropriately for a given user with a "CustomUserChangeForm"

Comment: Your justification for not using a custom user class doesn't make much sense here; why would a user need multiple positions and bios? OP was right originally, they belong on the CustomUser class.

Comment: Hi, i dont have the purpose of this code, in my head its just like an RPG game where the user move, use skill and loose HP, maybe i'm in the wrong